# Windows 10 manual proxy setup doesn't do anything

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, proxy, default-settings

I am trying to set a proxy in windows "Manual Proxy Setup" to apply on chrome or any other web browser, But there is no sign of any change in the entire system.

[image]

I'm not getting any connection error anywhere and my IP doesn't change at all. It seems it doesn't apply for some reason.

Result of `netsh winhttp show proxy` says `Direct access (no proxy server)`

Tried this command in CMD: `set HTTP_PROXY=http://219.78.228.211:80` with no luck, And also applied the same changes in multiple Windows 10 virtual machines of 19043 and 19044 but the same thing applies as well.

Windows Version 10.0.19044.1618

Comment: WinHTTP is something else entirely by the way. Don't worry about that. Different web browsers may or may not use the system proxy settings. Firefox for example doesn't by default.

Comment: @DanielB I have set Both Firefox and chrome proxy settings to "Use System Proxy", The same result.

Comment: Why are you expecting your IP address to change while connected to a proxy? Typically a systems IP address does not change with a proxy configuration. Are you sure a proxy service is running at that address on that port. A proxy on port 80 would be unusual

Comment: @Ramhound You got a point but chrome doesn't show any sign of an HTTP proxy is applied. I expected some sort of connection error on fail or a change in IP in case of success. I have used some public and premium http/https proxies but just nothing changes at all.

Comment: I am not saying your connected or something isn’t wrong. I am just saying your IP address won’t change. How do you know a proxy server is configured at that address?